# how to change padding of the content container without changing the other layout which is inherited from the same code

Tags: css

I need to change the container padding. Particularly the width. I tried to find the code in style.css and found this code.

```
.center{ width:85%; margin:0 auto;}
```

I adjusted the width to 100% but it took the logo and the menu bar to the left side with itself.
I am searching for the solution to this. Also I want to apply this css code to only one page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're changing the width, you're going to change how that element interacts with other elements, so changing the width is a bad idea.

You should stick to just changing the padding.

```
.center {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px; //insert whatever padding you want here
}
```

If this is affecting the width of the element, then try applying:

```
.center {
    //your existing css for this selector, then:
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you want to apply this change to one page only, your best bet is probably to add a class to the html element that you're trying to modify and target that class with your new padding.